# Entity Framework Navigation Properties Are Null

Tags: entity-framework

I am having a problem where my Entity Framework navigation properties are null.  My two models are Order and OrderLine:

```
class Order
{
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrderLine> Lines { get; set; }
}

class OrderLine
{
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

My Context class looks like this

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasKey(p => p.OrderNumber);

        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderLine>()
            .HasKey(p => new { p.OrderNumber, p.LineNumber });

        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderLine>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.Order)
            .WithMany(p => p.Lines)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.OrderNumber);

    }
}
```

When I run the following code, my orders load (the message box shows the correct count), but the Order.Lines collection is null.

```
List<Order> orders = (from o in context.Orders select o).ToList();

// This message box shows the correct number of orders
MessageBox.Show(orders.Count.ToString());

// This line crashes because orders[0].Lines is null.  There are lines in the database that should be joining to orders[0]
MessageBox.Show(orders[0].Lines.Count.ToString());
```

I've looked at a lot of examples, and I can't figure out what I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: Is there a reason you have OrderLine being configured twice?

Comment: @BenRubin, as a suggestion, you don't need to create a query to load all the orders. You can do this: `context.Orders.ToList()`, but be careful with this because when you have a lot of rows it could be very inefficient, so try to filter first before call the `ToList()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the navigation properties as `virtual` in order to be lazy loaded:

```
public class Order
{
    //...
    public virtual ICollection<OrderLine> Lines { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLine
{
    //...
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

For more info check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx) to see all the requirements you need to follow.

Comment: I've tried it with and without my navigation properties being virtual, and both ways have the same problem.

Comment: Have you disabled explicitly lazy loading on your context?

Comment: Ok, I see my problem.  I read that page you posted and the problem was that my classes weren't public.  Thank you octavioccl.

Comment: oh I thought that was a fact for you. You're welcome, glad I could help